# $\operatorname{grad}(f)$ definition and extra basis term.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Some preliminary definitions. On page 342 of Lee's Smooth Manifold he concludes that $\hat{g}(\operatorname{grad} f)(X) = Xf$ where $\hat{g}$ is the isomorphism between $TM \to T^*M$, the tangent bundle and co-tangent bundle.

Now according to Lee, $\hat{g}^{-1}(\omega) = g^{ij}\omega_j \frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}$

But what I found is that,

> \begin{align} \hat{g}(\hat{g}^{-1}(df))(X)
>  &=\hat{g}(g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial }{\partial
>  x^j})(X)\\
>  &=g_{ij}g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial
>  x^j} X^i\\ &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial
>  x^j} X^i \\ &= X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial
>  }{\partial x^j} \text{because g is symmetric, so we can bring X to the
>  front} 
> \end{align}

But $Xf = X^i(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$. So there is an extra basis term coming out of my reduction. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have mixed the indices a bit. In the first line we should have

$$\hat{g}(\hat{g}^{-1}(df))(X)
 =\hat{g}\left(g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial
 x^\color{red}{i}}\right) X$$

For the second line you shouldn't  keep $Y=g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{i}}$ when you evaluate $g$. Instead you should just take the $k$-th component. This is explicitly stated at the beggining of p. 342. Indeed $\hat{g}(Y)(X)$ should produce a number, not a vector like in your case. Thus we would get:

$$\hat{g}(\hat{g}^{-1}(df))(X)
 =\hat{g}\left(g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial
 x^i}\right) X = g_{ik} X^i g^{kj}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} = \delta^j_i X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} = X^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} = Xf$$

Note that $Xf =  X^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\color{red}{i}}$, not $Xf =  X^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$, as you have mentioned in the last line.

**REMARK:** The reason why I take the $k$-th component is because we have already used $j$ for the coordinate representation of $\hat{g}^{-1}(df)$. Thus $g(X)(Y) = g_{ij}X^iY^k$. In fact I believe that this is the reason behind your confusion in the probem.

Comment: Reading this again, I think I figured out my problem. Lee's notations are really easy to mess up. In my brain I know $\hat{g}$ and its inverse are different, but translating that via my hand is something different. Basically $\hat{g}$ strips off the basis vectors in $TM$ and leaves you with their components and $\hat{g}^{-1}$ strips off the basis vectors in $T^*M$ (I guess they would just be the linear functionals 1-forms $dx^\mu$) and leave you with their smooth components $\omega_i$

Comment: @Hawk Well, if you are applying $\hat{g}(Y)$ to some vector field $X$ you can think that it strips the basis vectors and combines the coordinates of $Y$ and $X$ in a nice manner. Similar thing happens when you apply $\hat{g}^{-1}(\omega)$ to a function $f$. I guess that way of seeing it would help you during such evaluation.

Comment: @Hawk However what $\hat{g}$ really does is it sends vector fields to covector fields, while $\hat{g}^{-1}$ does the opposite. So $\hat{g}$ "switches" between the basis $\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}\right\}$ and its dual basis $\left\{dx^i\right\}$ in some nice manner.

Comment: @Hawk This could be best seen by applying $\hat{g}$ to a coordinate vector fields. So we have:

$$\hat{g}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^1}\right) = g_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^1}\right)^i dx^j = g_{1j} dx^j$$

Now apply the inverse to $g_{1j} dx^j$ to get:

$$\hat{g}^{-1}\left(g_{1j} dx^j\right) = g^{ij}g_{1j}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i} = \delta_1^i \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}  = \frac{\partial }{\partial x^1}$$